# "Not in set" notation within the set definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am trying to define a set such that for two elements $a$ and $b$, such that $a$ can only be in the set if $b$ is not. For example, lets say $a$ is a natural number and $b = 5 - a$. I defined it as $S = \lbrace { a | \exists b: (a + b = 5) \wedge a \in \mathbb{N} \wedge b \notin S}\rbrace$. My question is, can I use S on the right hand side of the definition of S itself?
(The example is very trivial. It is just for clarity.)

Comment: You mean, B is not in set A?

Comment: Please fix your LaTeX by closing the set brace. Otherwise it's not easy to see what exactly you want to say.

Comment: No, a new set S. If B is already in the set, then A cannot be. How do I express that in set builder notation for S?

Comment: I edited $B = 5 - A $ to $B = A - 5$.

Comment: @SamRubenAbraham Why would you have done that? $B=5-A$ is the same as $A+B=5$.

Comment: Ok, sorry... I am a beginner.

Comment: I was in a hurry and didn't go through the question fully.

Comment: I don't think I'm qualified enough to answer this one, but here's a suggestion: If $A$ belongs to a larger set(such as $\Bbb N$), then $S$ can be constructed based on the exclusion of $B$ from $\Bbb N$, i.e., $S=\{A\in \Bbb N\lvert A\neq B\}$, and then $B$ can be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is $3$ in the set? Only if $2$ is not.

Is $2$ in the set? Only if $3$ is not.

How do you know whether either $2$ or $3$ is in $S$? You can't, not without knowing whether either $2$ or $3$ is in $S$,

Hence for example either $S = \{0, 1, 2\}$ or $S = \{3, 4, 5\}$ could be $S$. And all sorts of other possibilities, e.g. $S = \{0, 2, 4\}$.

So $S$ is not uniquely defined.

Hence your definition is invalid.

In fact you can even make a case that $S = \{0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, \ldots\}$ because you can say, oh yes, but there exists $b$ as a negative integer.

Comment: I get your point. This set in particular does not need to be unique. Both S = { 0, 1, 2} or {3,4,5} would be valid. I am not aware that a set MUST be unique. Is that so? 
And my basic question is, can S be used in the definition of S itself? The example was something I came up in a hurry, not necessarily what I am solving.

Comment: If you define an object, in this case $S$, then it must be well defined. Otherwise you can't specify what its properties are. I'm sorry, but I can't get my head round the thought process that suggest it might be otherwise.

Comment: Further thoughts: you can define a set of sets "$\mathbb S := $ the set of all sets of the form $S$ where $S := \{a \in \mathbb N: (\exists b \in \mathbb N: a + b = 5 \land b \notin S\}$". I'm still wary of the self-referential aspect of the concept, but at least now you have a consistent way of referring to this set of all sets of this form. **NOTE**: you *must* specify the domain of $b$, I have assumed $\mathbb N$ like $a$.

Comment: Thank you. The self referential part is the point I am concerned about. Sorry if my hurried example took the focus somewhere else.